# What won't MySQL start?

Tags: mysql

MySQL will not start, and I need some help to figure out why.

```
$ download mysql-common
[sudo] password for zero: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-common is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.31-0ubuntu0.13.04.1) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Setting up libmysqlclient18:amd64 (5.5.31-0ubuntu0.13.04.1) ...

Setting up libdbd-mysql-perl (4.021-1) ... Setting up mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.31-0ubuntu0.13.04.1) ... Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.31-0ubuntu0.13.04.1) ... start: Job failed to start invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed. dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server: mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however: Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already Processing triggers for libc-bin ... ldconfig deferred processing now taking place Processing triggers for ureadahead ... Errors were encountered while processing: mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when - while installing - upstart tries to start mysqld and fails for some reason.

Please check the */var/log/syslog* or mysql logs in /var/log/mysql for errors while starting mysqld. That should help you debugging, what problem is blocking mysqld from starting correctly.

Others had successfully purged and reinstalled mysqld but that's only applicable if that is a new installation.